# Vncserver ignoes all config files | Tigervncserver

Tags: vnc, tightvncserver

I'm using TigerVnc Server running on a Ubuntu22 (running in a lxc container).
Everything works perfect, except the fact that the vncserver ignores all config files!

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Xvnc TigerVNC 1.12.0 - built 2022-03-25 17:06

I have already tried  all various possibilities (which I could find in any forum)

```
~/.vnc/vnc.conf  
~/.vnc/config 
/etc/vnc.conf
```

I just want to change some configuration like "geometry" and "localhost"

```
geometry="2000x400";
localhost="no";
```

As it is good described here:

[enter link description here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398905/vnc-server-only-listening-for-connections-from-localhost) or here  [enter link description here](https://tigervnc.org/doc/vncsession.html)

Tigervnc-Server is using my default directory; that works:
-> like "xstartup" is used also log files are created!

Comment: solved:

i ran vncserver as root, so thats the reason why my ~ home directory was ignored.
so no ~/.vnc/vnc.conf   is used luckily

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
I ran vncserver as root, so thats the reason why my ~ home directory was ignored. so no ~/.vnc/vnc.conf is used luckily